# Google Sheets formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Any of you guys know how I can write a formula to find the difference in minutes of 2 times.
example 9.15 -  9.30   answer should be 15, how do I get Google Sheets to tell me the difference in minutes between 2 times?

Comment: Did you try just using subtraction?

Comment: It works fine with 9.30 - 9.15 but what about 11.10 - 10.40 ???

Answer (score 2):

If you represent times as HH:MM (instead of HH.MM), then you can just use subtraction.

Comment: For example, I have 9:15 and 9:30 in 2 separate cells. When i change 9:15 to HH:MM it changes it to 03:36?? Really struggling with this, HELP PLEASE!!

Comment: If you have 9:15 in a cell, it is already in HH:MM format (you had been using a decimal instead of a colon).

Answer (score 2):

I saw that you had originally put 9.15 (with a decimal) instead of 9:15 (with a colon).  If so, then you taught Google Sheets to think of that cell as being a number.  It is thinking of the number, nine point one five.  When you reformat the cell to show as a time, it thinks 9.15 days after midnight on 1/1/1900.  It's just how Google Sheets measures dates/times.

So, here's what you need to do:

1. Highlight the cells that will contain times.
2. Format as time (HH:MM).
3. Retype the times.  E.g., A1=9:30 and B1=9:15
4. In another cell, enter your formula: =(A1-B1)*24
5. Set the format for this cell to be a number.

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all good practice to record times with a point to separate hours and minutes, but if you must:

```
=60*left(B2,find(".",B2))+right(B2,2)-60*left(A2,find(".",A2))-right(A2,2)
```

[image]

Two "decimal places" are required.

Answer (score 0):

= End time - Start time
or
=TEXT(B2-A2,"h:mm:ss")